# Issue using MultipartBody.Builder when uploading image/file to server

Tags: java, android, image, api

[logcat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBq25.png)

```
private void Save_Gallery_Image() {

    rest.ShowDialogue(getResources().getString(R.string.pleaseWait));

    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    MultipartBody.Builder builder = ApiClient.createmultipartbuilder(new String[]{"tid"},
            new String[]{Config.getUserid()},new String[]{"images[]"}, listOfImages);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.uploadImage(builder.build());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            rest.dismissProgressdialog();
            try {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    Save_Gall_responce(response.body().string());

                }
                else {

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            onApiFailure(call, t);
        }
    });

}
```

I'm getting error in logcat when using apiInterface and MultipartBody.Builder to upload image/file to server. Below is the interface code

```
 @Multipart
@POST("save-gallery")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody image);
```

Answer (score 0):

That Exception means that in your case the variable name is needed like this:

```
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part("Image") MultipartBody image);
```

Comment: it shows Sending request on null in logcat after making the changes